# How to debug disruptor performance?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

so I have code:

```
private void schedule(....) {
        long s = m_ringBuffer.next();            
.....
        m_logger.info("1 [{}]", s);
        m_ringBuffer.publish(s);                
.....
}

private void run(){
   .....
   while(true){
       ...
       final long availableSequence = m_barrier.waitFor(nextSequence);
       while (nextSequence <= availableSequence) {
              m_logger.info("2 [{}] [{}]", nextSequence, availableSequence);
             Task t = m_ringBuffer.get(nextSequence);
             m_logger.info("3");
             ...
        }
     } 
 }
```

.... 9 out of 10 times is fast but I would have cases like

```
13:35:46.365 [Thread-1] INFO  App - 1 [44905]
13:35:46.380 [Thread-2] INFO  App - 2 [44905] [44905]
13:35:46.380 [Thread-2] INFO  App - 3
```

I use BusySpinWaitStrategy and I have no idea what's going on in that 15 millis.. and the ring buffer is empty.

My Thread-1 and Thread-2 are pinned to their isolated cpu.

Is there any Linux system tool that will allow me to debug this, or look at what UNSAFE.get and UNSAFE.putOrderedInt is doing? (strace doesn't seem to help and it's slow)

My app also uses multiple Chronicle queues so I'm not sure if there's any "collision" there as there are UNSAFE call everywhere in Chronicle.

My Disruptor version is 3.4.2, using Java 8.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are GC settings that you use? By default in Java8 there is no `MaxGCPauseMillis` define so it may be the effect of GC that you are observing. Have you checked GC logs?

Comment: Yes I print out GC and Safepoint but neither seems to be the issue... one thing I notice is sometimes the waitFor would return but the availableSequence is actually less than nextSequence still..

Comment: What logging library are you using? Are you sure this latency is not introduced by the logging?

Comment: It's log4j2 I'm using..

Comment: @Mag Which operating system are you using? Also, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your problem.